# HotChocolate GraphQL - Unable to apply filtering or sorting for an ExtensionType for an POCO defined in Entity Framework

Tags: filtering, hotchocolate, type-extension

I am unable to apply UseFiltering method on a navigation property on an EF entity extended by ObjectTypeExtension. However, when I disable ObjectTypeExtension and directly apply [UseFiltering()] attribute on the EF generated class on the navigation property, the code works flawlessly. The challenge seems to emerge specifically when the ObjectExtensionType is enabled. The underlying objective is to avoid intertwining EF entity and HotChocolate code, prompting the use of ObjectExtensionType to enhance the entity's functionality – a key rationale behind leveraging Extension Types.

Line throwing error:

```
descriptor.Field(t => t.Brands).UseFiltering();
```

Error message:

```
1. Could not load type 'HotChocolate.Types.IInputType' from assembly 'HotChocolate.Types, Version=13.8.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. (Product.QL.Types.LobTeamType)

   at HotChocolate.Configuration.TypeInitializer.DiscoverTypes()
   at HotChocolate.Configuration.TypeInitializer.Initialize()
   at HotChocolate.SchemaBuilder.Setup.InitializeTypes(SchemaBuilder builder, IDescriptorContext context, IReadOnlyList`1 types)
   at HotChocolate.SchemaBuilder.Setup.Create(SchemaBuilder builder, LazySchema lazySchema, IDescriptorContext context)
   at HotChocolate.Execution.RequestExecutorResolver.CreateSchemaAsync(ConfigurationContext context, RequestExecutorSetup setup, RequestExecutorOptions executorOptions, IServiceProvider schemaServices, TypeModuleChangeMonitor typeModuleChangeMonitor, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at HotChocolate.Execution.RequestExecutorResolver.CreateSchemaServicesAsync(ConfigurationContext context, RequestExecutorSetup setup, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at HotChocolate.Execution.RequestExecutorResolver.GetRequestExecutorNoLockAsync(String schemaName, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at HotChocolate.Execution.RequestExecutorResolver.GetRequestExecutorAsync(String schemaName, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at HotChocolate.Execution.RequestExecutorProxy.GetRequestExecutorAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at HotChocolate.AspNetCore.HttpPostMiddlewareBase.HandleRequestAsync(HttpContext context)
   at HotChocolate.AspNetCore.HttpPostMiddlewareBase.InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.EndpointRouteBuilderExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass19_0.<<UseCancellation>b__1>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression.ResponseCompressionMiddleware.InvokeCore(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

```
//EF Entity    
public partial class LobTeam
    {
      public int LobTeamId { get; set; }
      public Guid LobTeamUid { get; set; }
      public string Name { get; set; } = null!;
      public int StatusId { get; set; }
      public virtual ICollection<LobTeamBrand> LobTeamBrands { get; set; } = new List<LobTeamBrand>();
      public virtual ICollection<Platform> Platforms { get; set; } = new List<Platform>();
      public virtual ICollection<Brand> Brands { get; set; }
     }

//ObjectTypeExtension class
    public sealed class LobTeamType : ObjectTypeExtension<LobTeam>
    {
        protected override void Configure(IObjectTypeDescriptor<LobTeam> descriptor)
        {
            descriptor
                .Field(t => t.LobTeamBrands)
                .Ignore();

            descriptor
                .Field(t => t.Brands)
                .UseFiltering();
        }
    }


//Program.cs file
builder.Services
    .AddGraphQLServer()
    .AddQueryType<ProductQuery>()
    .RegisterDbContext<ProductDataContext>(DbContextKind.Resolver)
    .AddProjections()
    .AddFiltering()
    .AddSorting()
    .AddTypeExtension<LobTeamType>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently one cannot use UseFiltering() on the base EF entity. Instead HotChocolate expects the field to be of an HotChocolate Object Extesion Type. So in your example above, create a BrandType objectExtension and used the BrandType to apply UseFiltering() on LobTeamType.
To take this to the next level I created a generic interceptor that will create the Object Extension Type and apply UseFiltering() at runtime, instead of me creating individual Types for every type. This helped me to apply filtering on all navigation properties of the type ICollection. Here's the code for it.

```
public class FilterCollectionTypeInterceptor : TypeInterceptor
{
    private static readonly List<string> _mappedTypes = new();

    private static bool IsCollectionType(Type t)
        => t.IsGenericType && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ICollection<>);

    public override void OnBeforeRegisterDependencies(ITypeDiscoveryContext discoveryContext, DefinitionBase? definition)
    {
        if (definition is not ObjectTypeDefinition objectTypeDefinition) return;

        if (objectTypeDefinition.RuntimeType.Name != "Object") return;

        var keyBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        for (var i = 0; i < objectTypeDefinition.Fields.Count; i++)
        {
            var field = objectTypeDefinition.Fields[i];
            if (field.ResultType is null || !IsCollectionType(field.ResultType)) 
                continue;

            keyBuilder.Clear(); // Clear StringBuilder for the next key
            keyBuilder.Append(objectTypeDefinition.Name.ToLower()).Append('.').Append(field.Name.ToLower());
            var key = keyBuilder.ToString();

            if (_mappedTypes.Contains(key)) 
                continue;

            var descriptor = field.ToDescriptor(discoveryContext.DescriptorContext);
            descriptor.UseFiltering(typeof(FilterInputType<>).MakeGenericType(field.ResultType.GenericTypeArguments[0]));
            objectTypeDefinition.Fields[i] = descriptor.ToDefinition();
            
            _mappedTypes.Add(key);
        }
    }
}
```